# Build an Xcode project on Windows

Tags: ios, xcode, renpy

I need to compile an Xcode project on Windows. I don't need to make one, because it is automatically generated. I am new to iOS development, and I don't plan to submit to the App Store or pay Apple 100$ to sign it, I just want to build an IPA I can install on my jailbroken device. This is just for personal use. When I tried setting up a vitrual Mac it always fails to boot. Is there any fix to that? Is this even possible?

Comment: But you can give that a [chance](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be building a hackintosh or getting ahold of a mac to use/buy.

If you have an intel computer that is somewhat modern, chances are you can install OS X on it (there might be a few inconsistencies that you may be able to iron out with a little time and money). Just do some research on your chipset. Maybe somethings are compatible and some aren't; you can fill those voids through buying considerably cheap hardware to get a fully working machine. Consult this page: [CustoMac: Component Buyer's Guide](https://www.tonymacx86.com/buyersguide/november/2016) to get a repository of confirmed supported components. There is also a huge [community](http://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh) on reddit that is more than helpful at assisting others who are trying to get their hackintosh working.

**If you do have an AMD there is still hope, I had my 8350 working on yosemite before I upgraded to an intel.** I can't link you to the unsigned iso, but you can search for it. The distro is by "Nerish", you can download the iso or find the kernel and manually install it.

I'm currently running an i7 6700k CPU with an Asus Sabertooth z170 Mark1 motherboard, 16gb ddr4 corsair ram, and a GTX  970. Everything is working well. I have both windows and OS X sierra installed so that I can do my normal business work and easily develop in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible (as of now). To build an Xcode project you need an environment, that is just not present on Windows. I mean a lot of libraries, frameworks and tools that are shipped with macOS.

One possible way is to try to find a working macOS VM / install a "Hackintosh", but be warned that both actions are illegal according to macOS ToS.

By the way, you don't need to pay Apple 99$ to install your software on a device. You just need a Mac.

Comment: Then I need a hacked macOS iso. But all of them are for Intel, and I have an AMD cpu. AFAIK Mac doesn't like AMD cpus, so can I fake that in VMWare somehow?

Comment: @LórántGerber unfortunately, it's been a while since I last explored this topic, so I don't think I can answer your question. I would try looking for help on specialized resources like https://www.tonymacx86.com and such. I'm not sure StackOverflow is a proper place for this discussion. Still, I wish you luck! :)

Comment: _By the way, you don't need to pay Apple 99$ to install your software on a device. You just need a Mac_ I believe this statement is wrong; you *do* need to have a valid membership in order to build for the device.

Comment: @phi Not anymore. You just need an Apple ID. If I'm not mistaken, you'll need to register on developer.apple.com, too, but that's all. It's not a full membership though. If I'm not mistaken, you won't be able push notifications, for instance. But you are now able to run your apps on actual devices without a paid membership.

Comment: @phi, for reference:  https://blog.ionicframework.com/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/